# Problems with showing rating stars in google search results - Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, google-search

I have the problem with displaying stars in google-search results.
Here, as an example, there are two links to the sites (driving schools in Denmark)
1. https://www.koereskoleoplysningen.dk/listing/skrivers-koreskole-allerod/ (rating stars not working)
2. https://www.koereskoleoplysningen.dk/listing/trekantens-koreskole-vejle/ (rating stars working).

I checked the validity of the star rating (using google search engine), by simply inputting in the mentioned cases:
1. koereskole oplysningen Skrivers Køreskole – Allerød
2. koereskole oplysningen Trekantens Køreskole – Vejle

The first school shows only the link, whereas the second one displays overall rating with total number of ratings correctly. I used https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool to check if both sites contains `AggregateRating` field (it contains all information about ratings) and both pages returns the same correct results (all pages contains  `AggregateRating` field).

This issue occurs also for other sites (I have more than 1000 listings and some of them as the mentioned examples, show ratings stars properly, some of them not).

I validated the sitemaps, website ranker show me the highest results, Yoast SEO is configured and also didn't return me any errors.

Comment: May be ask here https://support.google.com/webmasters/?hl=en#topic=3309469

Comment: I set all necessary information and all my sites (driving schools listings) contain  JSON-LD structured data. From the technical point of view, google has everything to generate structured data (such as stars) in the search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from our analysis there are three factors at play:

```
1   Trusted review sites

2   Schema markup

3   Site authority
```

[Source](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.hitsearchlimited.com/news/how-can-your-business-get-star-ratings-in-organic-search-results-id0318%3Fhs_amp=true)

Comment: First one has 45 ratings, second one: 106. I checked many of them (I got more than thousand in the database, and the problem occurs randomly and does not depend on number of ratings)

Comment: I mean reviews with 5 stars and text explaining the positive experience, not the rating.. Also recommend to ask this question on google webmaster forum..